# Dont work command 'django-admin.py startproject blog .'. IDE just show script and nothing happens

Tags: django, pycharm

I try to create a new Django project in Pycharm IDE. After correctly installing Django I try to do this command in the terminal `django-admin.py startproject blog .`, but IDE shows me this script in a new window and nothing happening. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: You need to add python in front of your command to actually run the program.

Comment: After i try to do fix command '(venv) D:\Учёба\Blog>python django-admin.py startproject blog .' i get message:
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe: can't open file 'django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: You would have to add django-admin.py to your PATH environment variable or use the absolute path of the file, however, django-admin.py is deprecated so you should use django-admin instead.